# Using SQL to find all possible combinations of column variables

Tags: mysql

I have a table in SQL which has N columns. Call them "Col1", "Col2", ..., "ColN". I can find out how many unique elements there are in Col1 by the query:

`select count(distinct Col1) from mytable`

and I can do this, independently for each column. Assuming I have M_1 unique elements in Col1, M_2 in Col2, etc., what single command can I use to find the total number of all possible combinations for my dataset? That is, what single query would calculate (M_1*M_2*...*M_N) for me?

PS: very new to SQL here, so I'm not sure if this matters - but I am using MySQL Workbench on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM YourTable) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM YourTable) AS t2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col3 FROM YourTable) AS t3
...
```

`CROSS JOIN` calculates the cross product between the given tables.

Another way to write it would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3, ...)
FROM YourTable AS t1
CROSS JOIN YourTable AS t2
CROSS JOIN YourTable AS t3
...
```

But probably the simplest would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1)*COUNT(DISTINCT col2)*COUNT(DISTINCT col3)*...
FROM YourTable
```

This doesn't require computing any cross-products, so it should be most efficient. If you have indexes on the columns, it won't even have to read the table data, it can all be done using the indexes.

Comment: +1 . . . Because I particularly like the third method.  However, these are not necessarily equivalent.  I could let you suffer to figure out why, but the reason is `NULL` values.  The first treats these as a distinct value, the second and third do not.